# Legacy Code, C++ in VisualStudio using 2013 not building in 2017 and need 2013 installed on the computer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I got handed some legacy code and was asked to make an installer out of it.  I can do this using innoscript and a computer that runs visual studio 2013.  It works on any computer that has 2013 installed on it.  WILL NOT on any other.

I know that in order to get this code to build i need to go into a bunch of files like atomic, etc and comment out this mc_gee section in the include files of 2013.

Also 2013 needs to be installed on the comnpputer in order to run EVEN when installed from an installer that i create using innoscript.

I tried just installed the 2013 c++ redist onto the computer.  But that doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me out here?  It wont build in 3017 at all. no matter what we try i've been told its impossible because they stopped support for something it needed in 2013.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might be of help in at least determining what components you need to include in your installation.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, will Give this a try tomorrow!